# buildConfigField VS class field? resValue VS resource

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

What's the advantage of putting a `buildConfigField` to my flavor via gradle in comparison with a `Constants.java` file per flavor?

Also what's the advantage of putting a `resValue` to my flavor via gradle in comparison with regular resources per flavor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What's the advantage of putting a buildConfigField to my flavor via gradle in comparison with a Constants.java file per flavor?

First, it is less typing. With `buildConfigField`, it's one line of Groovy code per flavor. With `Constants.java`, it is a separate Java class per flavor.

Second, the value could be code generated by Groovy code in the build script, and that's a whole lot easier than code generating a Java class (though the latter is certainly possible).

> Also what's the advantage of putting a resValue to my flavor via gradle in comparison with regular resources per flavor?

Pretty much the same as above.

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer. If the `resValue` string needs translation, then is there a choice but to put in string.xml for the flavour?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri: I suspect so. I cannot think of a good way to do that purely from Gradle.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a gradle build time advantage to use buildConfigField versus resValue?

Comment: @benzabill: Not that I am aware of, though I have not researched the issue.